# Unable to connect SQL Server on local Machine from Network

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have installed SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2008. But when I connect to the same server in SQL Server on local machine connected to LAN it is not connecting.

The error is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following

Go to the computer where you installed SQL and open SQL server configuration manager

Go to **SQL server Network Configuration** --> TCP/IP and make sure it is enabled.
Also check the IP Addresses and make sure that the **port under IPALL is 1433**.

Next for the purpose of testing only, disable windows firewall or antivirus firewall for the machine (you can turn it on later and check again)

If you have installed SQL express, a named version by default will get installed.
So open your SSMS on the other computer from where you want to connect and type the following as server name
If SQL Express: [IPADDRESS OF MAIN PC]\MSSQLSERVER,1433
If enterprise: [IPADDRESS OF MAIN PC]

Type the way you are authenticating and you should be in.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `RUN`->`Services.msc`-> `Start the service of SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)`

Then try to again to connect